# Unity не работает клик на UI элемент

Tags: c#, unity3d, ui

```
void OnPointerOver(PointerEventData eventData) {        
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {      
        print("Clicked");
    }       
}
```

В игре есть инвентарь, и при клике на какой-либо слот беру предмет, но перед этим хочу вообще проверить, работает ли клик, и данный код не срабатывает, сам скрипт висит на UI объекте, также пробовал применить `OnMouseOver()`, но также молчание в ответ. Как поступить?

Comment: [Возможно то, что нужно](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41391708/how-to-detect-click-touch-events-on-ui-and-gameobjects)

Comment: для начала проверьте этот метод без  никаких условных операторов. Я думаю что все будет работать. И что такое место для этой проверки не подходит.

Comment: А другие кнопки в это время работают?

Comment: Вам нужно что-то делать с логикой кода. Либо перенести `GetMouseButtonDown()` в `Update()`, либо в `OnPointerOver` использовать другое условие, т.к. `GetMouseButtonDown()` необходимо использовать в `Update()`. [Почитайте тут](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonDown.html)

Comment: ...И чем плох компонент `Button`?